# How do I have jQuery to select custom HTML tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html:

```
Coral8 <del class="diffmod">SQL, to</del><ins class="diffmod">SQL,to</ins> improve
```

I want to grab the `<ins>` tags. Those seem to be custom HTML tags, so I don't have an ID or classname.

Any thoughts on which jQuery selector can be used to grab them?

Comment: It would seem better to do this with xpath as this must be from an xml file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) `$('ins')`. It's little effort to try it out yourself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3432853</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert($('ins').text()); // SQL,to
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Coral8 <del class="diffmod">SQL, to</del><ins class="diffmod">SQL,to</ins> improve
    </body>
</html>
```

[It works](http://jsfiddle.net/XCLZ3/). Those are by the way [**legitimately valid** HTML tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ins.asp).